# Get Registered or Created Date for a device in Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get the "Registered" or "Created Date" of a device in Azure AD using the Graph API.  I can see the Registered date from the Azure Portal but the property isn't listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/device?view=graph-rest-1.0

Is there another way to get it?